# Xcode 11.5 Post-Update Error: Unable to activate constraint with anchors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode11.4

I just updated to Xcode 11.5 and suddenly my application is throwing up this error (listed below).

My application has a TabBar as a foundation and houses different views for each of the five TabBar Items. All views work fine, except for the 3rd one, where on clicking the icon, I get the below error message.

This view has a segControl that changes data in a tableView. I've added pull to refresh and a search functionality. There's also a UILabel that appears when data can't be pulled / no internet scenario and is otherwise hidden.

**Error**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000064b4c0 "UILabel:0x7fb6dd8b8b80'Day 1'.centerY"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000649780 "UIView:0x7fb6dd4b89d0.centerY"> because they have no common ancestor. Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Now, I haven't changed this piece of code at all and it was working perfectly fine till the update happened. So I'm confused how to fix it.

I see that there might be some label and view conflicting their constraint hierarchies but I can't seem to figure out which ones and how to fix them.

Also there is nothing in my code that refers to 'Day 1' and I'm not adding any subViews programmatically.

**Troubleshooting done so far**

1. Discarded all code changes - *still the same issue*
2. Rolled back code to a previous working time through time machine - *still the same issue*
3. Rolled back Xcode to 11.4.x - *still the same issue*
4. Debugged my code, step by step - *everything seems okay*
5. Deleted any label or additional views - *still throws the error*
6. Reset the constraints to auto-constraints - *still the same issue*

**Current Constraints** [after discarding all code, working earlier]

```
 label.top = top - 9 
 bottom = label.bottom + 1 
 label.leading = leading + 8 
 label.centerX = centerX
```

These are the only constrains, as I added a view below the tableView and that view contains the label.

[These are auto-constraints]

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the constraints you added

Comment: Edited my question with this info. These are all auto-constraints. Didn't add any specifically by myself and it worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out the bug - it seems the update flipped over a custom class I was using, which in turn missed the reference to a dependency.

After reverting the custom class (in the storyboard - tableViewCell) correctly, it worked.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/xcode-how-to-fix-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-valu) was the inspiration to try out this solution.